# javaScript multiply two numbers and show the result into third html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take a number from my html form and then multiply it with a number from my JavaScript function and displaying the result in another html input. Want I want is when the user click on the result input area then only the multiplication result shows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("km").value;
    var z = 14;
    var x = y * z;
    document.getElementById("bill").innerHTML = x;


  }
<table>
<tr> 
   <td>Total Kms Run</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="km" name="km" required>
   </tr>
    <tr> 
   <td>Total Bill</td>
   <td><input type="text" id = "bill" name="bill" required onclick="myFunction()">
   </tr>
</table
```

Comment: You are adding numbers in code and saying as multiplying in question

Comment: also, should it not just be ```var x = y * z``` ? where is the ```Number(y)``` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Change like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {

   var y = document.getElementById("km").value;
    var z = 14;
    var x = y * z;
    document.getElementById("bill").value = x;


  }</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the numbers, not multiplying them :).

That aside, `input`s don't have `innerHTML`, you need to set the `value`:

```
document.getElementById("bill").value = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made many syntax mistakes in html

```js
function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("km").value;
    var z = 14;
    var x = Number(y) * Number(z);
    document.getElementById("bill").value = x;

}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr> 
       <td>Total Kms Run</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="km" name="km" required ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
       <td>Total Bill</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="bill" name="bill" required onclick="myFunction()"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```